# icon slider in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi I want to insert an automatic sections for icons like http://www.nestle.com/ section of A selection of our brands is there any step by step guide for do it in sharepoint 2013
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a CSS carousel as follows:

1. Edit the SharePoint page where you want the carousel to live.
2. Insert a content editor web part.
3. Create multiple elements with the same class name eg.
   `<img class="mySlides" src="img_fjords.jpg"> <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg">`
4. As buttons to scroll eg.
   `<button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
   <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>`

   5. Add a little JavaScript for image selection eg.
      `var slideIndex = 1;
      showDivs(slideIndex);
      function plusDivs(n) {
          showDivs(slideIndex+= n);
      }
      function showDivs(n) {
          var i;
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].style.display ="none"; 
          }
          x[slideIndex-1].style.display ="block"; 
      }`

That's it. 
Code sourced from the excellent W3Schools. See it in action here:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update images on the regular basis then hard coding the images in the content editor web part is not a good idea.  This is where you can consider Display Templates.

Have a look at this.  You should be able to customise the size/style as per your requirement.

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results

Comment: I want to use below jquery how can I use it in sharepoint I want a full width responsive slider   http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html